# php 5.1.6 json_encode and codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

Im building a codeigniter app which uses json_encode to provide ajax data in many places... today I learned that the server has php 5.1.6 which doesnt support this method (or json_decode).. what can I do?? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed json_encode and json_decode for jquery grid.
I tried upgradephp but json_encode didnt seem to work with jquery grid so I deleted that function from the file and added [this one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#82904). json_decode seems to work just fine though.

Answer (score 8):

There is an emulation of json_encode() in [upgradephp](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp). Just include() that script, and you don't need to rewrite anything.
As alternative you can use [PEAR::PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat). IIRC it has an emulation of that too.
(There are [further](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.html) alternative implementation floating around; but often object-style and not as fast and designed to emulate the core function.)

You can set them up with `auto_prepend_file=` even. If you just want the JSON extension enabled, there are other sources of course.

Comment: Well, I didn't know those existed. Thanks for pointing them out, all I have experience of is Services_JSON and Zend_Json.

Comment: http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat has the nicer code, and you can cherry-pick only whatever function you need; but it's less complete currently.  
And actually I think Zend_Json is better for development, because it has error reporting. Where the native PHP json_decode() has none.

Comment: That upgradephp link is gold!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Services_JSON if CodeIgniter can use it instead of PHP 5.2's json_* functions - I know Zend_Framework has Zend_Json which uses json_* functions if available, otherwise it uses its own implementation in userland PHP code as a fallback.

Of course, if you have access to the server to compile PHP, you could try the extension or upgrading to PHP 5.2 (a better solution).

EDIT: I would take the route of compatibility layers as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The **[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** is added since (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0), it is supported in your version too, you should give it a try :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, 5.1.6 supports json_decode and json_encode, but they can be a bit weird. As in, if you feed it invalid JSON, such as if you have a blank key, it will die without any warnings or errors. But I use json_encode and json_decode every day in a 5.1.6 environment. It's totally possible.